# How can I send e-mail when comment is added for commit on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I've been using GitLab(version 7.1.0.pre).

I want to receive e-mail when someone adds a comment for my commit.
I read GitLab document, but I couldn't find the sentence written about this.

Is it impossible to send e-mail when comment is added for commit?
(I know that I can add this feature by forking original code and write myself.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will get email when someone comment on your commit when both cases true:

- commit author email == your gitlab account email
- you have at least participating level for notification settings in this project